# Should I still use case insensitive file system in macOS Mojave?

Tags: filesystem

I switched to MacBook from Linux OS. In the beginning, I was using macOS High Sierra and people recommended to use *case-insensitive* file system because some apps may not work with *case-sensitive* file system.

Now I have upgraded to macOS Mojave, I am wondering if this is still true. I really don't like case-insensitive file system. It's just weird to me. I am just wondering when I can use case sensitive file system without any problems.

Thanks a lot.

---

#### P.S.

There is one article from 2017 talking about Adobe software don't work well on case sensitive filesystems:

- [Should You Format Your Mac Hard Drive To Be Case Sensitive Or Not
  Case Sensitive?](https://itnerd.blog/2017/11/17/should-you-format-your-mac-hard-drive-to-be-case-sensitive-or-not-case-sensitive)